# c++/cli dll wrapper for native c++ to be used in LabView

Tags: c++, c++-cli, wrapper, shared-ptr, labview

I'm trying to write a c++/cli wrapper for IO Industries Core2 DVR, which will then be used by LabView. The company provided a SDK with with all the headers (**written in c++**) and boost library. I've managed to build a wrapper that builds and LabView is able to see the function through the .net pallet.

```
// ManagedProject.h

#pragma once
#include "core_api_helper.h"
#include "core_api.h"


using namespace System;
using namespace CoreApi;

namespace ManagedProject {

//Setup class
public ref class Setup
{
private:

public:
    unsigned int initializeTest();

};
}
```

// This is the DLL Wrapper.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "ManagedProject.h"
#include "core_api_helper.h"
#include "core_api.h"
#include "resource.h"

using namespace CoreApi;
using namespace Common;
using namespace ManagedProject;

//Global handles

//A handle to the Core Api
InstanceHandle g_hApi;

//A handle to the Core Api Device Collection
DeviceCollectionHandle g_hCoreDeviceCollection;


unsigned int Setup::initializeTest()
{

try
{
    //Initialize the Core API (must be called before any other Core API functions)
    //Returns a handle to the Core Api
    g_hApi = Instance::initialize();

    // get a collection of Core devices
    g_hCoreDeviceCollection = g_hApi->deviceCollection();

    unsigned int deviceCount = g_hCoreDeviceCollection->deviceCount();

    return deviceCount;
}
catch (GeneralException& e)
{
    e.what();
    return 3;

}

}
```

However when I run LabView through Visual studio 2015 in debug mode I run into the problem below, and what is returned to LabView is the 3 from the catch block.

[First break in debug mode (NULL ptr)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFrW1.png)
**NOTE:** InstanceHandle is a shared_ptr

As can be seen the variable is a NULL pointer, the same thing happens for the g_hCoreDeviceCollectoin as well. I think I need to Instantiate it with the new command but am a little unsure as InstanceHandle is a shared_ptr.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Who are the chumps downvoting and not leaving any feedback? This looks very much like a valid question with plenty of supporting material.

Comment: Thanks, I would like some feedback as to why they down voted so I could form a better question in the future.

Comment: Is it possible that the Core2 code is unable to find one of its DLLs or a dependent DLL?  You may want to run LabView via the dependency walker Profiler and see if there's a missing dependency when your code attempts to initialize Core (http://dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: Another suggestion is to create a super-basic C++/CLI application which loads your assembly (DLL) and calls your setup object and see if that works. If it does, perhaps the issue is an interaction between LabView and your code (or Core)

Comment: Good idea jschroedl, I'll give this a try. I did end up getting it to work while just using a c++ dll wrapper to interface with LabVIEW, by using _declspec(dllexport).

Answer (score 1):

The C++/CLI has great feature called [mixed mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2012/11/14/ccli-and-mixed-mode-programming/). You can uses both managed and native  data types in the same code (in the same C++/CLI class). Try to use object from that SDK written in C++ directly in your wrapper.

Comment: I ended up rewriting the code in a C++ dll wrapper and it works fine, just have to manually export functions (__ddeclspec(dllexport)). I think that there is a problem with going from native C++ to the .net framwork to LabView. As others have hinted I believe that the problem is that Labview fails to see the dependent DLL. I'll use dependency walker Profiler to see if that was the problem.